# Изменение языка в input type date

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, form

Здравствуйте! Есть `input[type="date"]`, проблема в том, что при отсутствии изначально установленного `value`, поле отображается на русском языке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли каким-то образом поменять его на английский?

```html
<input type="date">
```

Comment: Если для себя - то в настройках браузера, ибо форматирование то системное - привязано к клиентским настройкам. Если у клиента - то никак, покуда у него настроен русский язык. В английском варианте будет иное форматирование. Постом он (всегда) отправит `yyyy-mm-dd` к слову. [enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721647/how-to-make-input-type-date-display-the-date-in-localized-format-in-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

Язык берется из настроек браузера. И нативными методами не меняется (насколько я знаю). Сам этим вопросом маялся давненько. Вот есть костыли http://web-sputnik.info/javascript/56-krossbrauzernyj-input-type-date-vypadayushchij-kalendar-v-pole-vvoda-daty